# Delete all the lines that start with a specific word from multiple (700+) text files

Tags: windows, perl, text, file-io

I have about 700 text files in a folder, and each of them looks like this:

```
ATOM     46  H17 21Q A   1       8.755   9.236  19.160  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     47  H18 21Q A   1       4.986  13.632  21.286  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     48  H19 21Q A   1       4.073  12.279  20.536  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     49  H20 21Q A   1       4.447  12.245  22.293  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     50  H21 21Q A   1      -0.059   3.744  18.524  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     51  H22 21Q A   1       0.915   2.266  18.827  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     52  H23 21Q A   1      -0.811   2.321  19.321  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     53  H24 21Q A   1      -0.126  -0.895  21.075  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     54  H25 21Q A   1       1.167   0.041  20.250  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     55  H26 21Q A   1       1.247  -0.230  22.024  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM     56  H27 21Q A   1       4.391   7.539  23.280  1.00 10.00           H
CONECT    1    2   30   31   32
CONECT    2    1    3   33   34
CONECT    3    2    5   18
CONECT    4    5   19   35
CONECT    5    3    4    6
CONECT    6    5   24   26
CONECT    7    8   12   24
```

what I am trying to do is to write a Perl script, able to process my 700 files while deleting all the lines that start with the word CONECT.  At the same time I want to save the file under its original name.
Unfortunately I only managed to open a single file (21Q) and to save it in an empty file that I created (21Q_2), not quite what I wanted.

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use File::Slurp;


open(my $in, '<', 'C:\perl_old_test\TRP_ligands_PDB\21Q.txt', )
or die "Cannot open input.txt: $!";

open(my $out, '>', 'C:\perl_old_test\TRP_ligands_PDB\21Q_2.txt')
or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!";

while (<$in>) {
print $out $_ unless /\bCONECT\b/;
}

close($in);
close($out);
```

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thank you very much,
Arianna

Comment: forgot to mention: I am using windows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) functionality:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'C:\perl_old_test\TRP_ligands_PDB\21Q.txt'

local @ARGV = ($file);
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    print if ! /\bCONECT\b/
}
unlink "$file$^I";
```

For additional methods for editing a file, read: [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a simple Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ni.bak -e 'print unless /^CONECT/' <filename glob>
```

The `-n` flag assumes this loop around the code you wish to execute:

```
while (<>) {
   # code 
}
```

The `-i` modifies your text files in place, `.bak` creates a backup of the original file in case you want both copies.

The `-e` flag indicates that Perl should execute this code.

`<filename glob>` should be replaced by a pattern that globs together all the files you want to examine. For instance if you wanted all files it would be `*`, or all files that have the .txt extension would be `*txt`.

Comment: Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1. Not sure about the meaning of that. Thanks!

Comment: @HunterMcMillen the OP is on windows.

Comment: @Miller Does the windows shell not support globbing of some kind? I am not super familiar with it.

Comment: It does not (but can with some hacks).  Additionally, the OP needs to use double quotes instead of single to get the command to work.  The following can work though:  `perl -ni.bak -e "BEGIN {@ARGV = <*.txt>} print unless /^CONECT/"`

Comment: @Miller Do you see any mistakes in this code: 
    C:\Users\rmgzaod>perl -ni.bak -e "BEGIN {@ARGV = <C:/path_to_folder/*.txt>} print unless /^CONECT/"

Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3821450 I see no mistakes in that one-liner if used on a windows system.  That should work for you.